# how to know if squid reverse proxy is installed and working well in centos6

Tags: centos, squid

I'm Gowri Shankar and i have been trying to learn linux for the past one month(which is awesome as everytime i configure something correctly it gives immense joy to me). Currently i'm learning squid reverse proxy server. i installed and configured it with mixed success which led me to this question "how to know if your configuration is correct?" as i can't seem to find a good resource on that in google and when i restart it ,squid  seems to work without coughing up errors. So, thought of coming here and ask the experts on how it is done.

Answer (score 0):

If it's working is a thing, and if it's well configured is another  thing.

to check if it working you can have a test with telnet

```
telnet localhost 80 <--put here the port squid is listening on
GET / HTTP/1.1
host:my.ownsite.tld

<-there may be here two time ENTER or CTRL+ENTER depending on your telnet config
```

this must display your site if well configured